# Error (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error) for POST from httpClient but works in Postman

Tags: json, rest, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, internal-server-error

I'm getting this error (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error) when I'm trying to do a POST in my REST client application, using HttpClient.

Please let me know where it could be going wrong.

Here is my code snippet. Am including the headers to accept application/json as content type

```
HashMap<String, String> defaultHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
defaultHeaders.put("content-type", "application/json");

request = new HttpPost(requestString);
if (sPayload != null) {
    payload = new StringEntity(sPayload);
    ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(payload);
}
```

Comment: I do not see the headers being set in the code you have pasted here. Can you try adding header like request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: Also, check the payload which you are passing whether its in json format or not.

Comment: Yes i added the headers and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please set the headers in the code as below

```
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

It will work.